# Unexpected template string expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I learn from tutorial and want to make ProductScreen.js and Product.js and I became this warnings, what is the problem?

**product.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Rating from './Rating';

export default function Product(props) {
    const {product} = props;

    return (
        <div key={product._id} className="card">
        <a href= '/product/${product._id}'> // Line 9                  
            <img className="medium" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
        </a>
        <div className="card-body">
        <a href='/product/${product._id}'>  //Line 13
                <h2>{product.name}</h2>
            </a>
           <Rating 
           rating={product.rating} 
           numReviews={product.numReviews}
           ></Rating>
            <div className="price">{product.price}lv</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong quote characters for those strings. Also I *think* you don't need the surrounding `{ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JS template literals wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

What you want is:

```
`/product/${product._id}`

// and

`/product/${product._id`

// Note the backticks "`" instead of single quote marks "'"
```

Comment: I changed that in my code but I again have this error. I updated code .

Comment: @nik_kolev You don't have the correct quotes still

Comment: Yes, my mistake . It works . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using incorrect quotes in templates. There must be `

Comment: It's tricky to type a solitary code-stylized backtick.  Edit your post and surround the backtick(s) with `<code>` markup.